# Why do I get an AssertionError when trying to load a saved PPO model using stable_baselines3 in Python?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am taking my first steps in Reinforcement Learning with python and am trying a very basic example, but I am running into a problem I can't find the answer for.

Training and saving the basic PPO model seems to work, **but when I try to load the model via `model = PPO.load(PPO_path, env=env)` i get the following error message**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PATRICK\200_Python_Projekte\CafeDelGatto\venv\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 730, in load
    model._setup_model()
  File "C:\PATRICK\200_Python_Projekte\CafeDelGatto\venv\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py", line 158, in _setup_model
    self.clip_range = get_schedule_fn(self.clip_range)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PATRICK\200_Python_Projekte\CafeDelGatto\venv\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\utils.py", line 91, in get_schedule_fn
    assert callable(value_schedule)
AssertionError
```

The only related topic I could find was https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/172, but this seems to be a version conflict. Since I am just training the model and instantly trying to load it, I dont have different python versions.

Here is my whole code:

```
import os
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_dataset_ops import model_dataset

env_name = 'CartPole-v0'
env = gym.make(env_name)

log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')

env = gym.make(env_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)

PPO_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_model')
model.save(PPO_path)

del model

model = PPO.load(PPO_path, env=env)
```

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

This fixed it for me: https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1131

Quoting Quentin Gallouédec (user "qgallouedec"):
"This issue has been fixed with #1123 and will be part of v1.7.0
Should be solved if you install the bleeding-edge-version of stable-baselines3"

Installing the bleeding-edge-version is done by running command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3
```

(or if this should ever be changed in the future, whatever it says on this website https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html#bleeding-edge-version).